# How do I update the class of a jQuery Draggable Item with the Parent ID that it's dropped into?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, addclass

I have a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/radmktryan/qfghjnm6/

My code:

HTML

```
<table id="#our_table" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
    <th>Stage 1</th>
    <th>Stage 2</th>
    <th>Stage 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="stage1" data-uid="stage1">
        <span class="event" id="a" draggable="true">aaa</span>
        <span class="event" id="b" draggable="true">bbb</span>
    </td>
    <td id="stage2" data-uid="stage2">
        <span class="event" id="c" draggable="true">ccc</span>
        <span class="event" id="d" draggable="true">ddd</span>
    </td>
    <td id="stage3" data-uid="stage3">
        <span class="event" id="e" draggable="true">eee</span>
        <span class="event" id="f" draggable="true">fff</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.event').on("dragstart", function (event) {
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('.event').on("drop", function (event) {
        var parentStage = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        $(this).addClass(parentStage);
        console.log(parentStage);

    });
    $('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.type === 'drop') {
            var data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text',$(this).attr('id'));
            de=$('#'+data).detach();
            de.appendTo($(this));   
        };
    });
})
```

What I want to accomplish: I want to update the class of an item (which is a 'span') when it is 'dropped' into another table cell. The class to be changed, should be inherited from it's parent table cell.

I am able to pull the correct ID, however, it's 'class' is being assigned to the wrong span item.

I'm guessing that my code is wrong when it comes to the 'drop' part.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were trying to add the class to the element when the `drop` event was fired on one of the `span` elements. In doing so, you were actually adding the parent element's `id` to the `span` element that you were dropping the draggable element on.

The `drop` event listener for the `.event` elements should either be removed:

```
$('.event').on("drop", function (event) {
  // ...
  // I removed this event listener since you never intended
  // to drop span elements inside of other span elements.
});
```

Or you could change the `drop` event listener to a `dragend` event listener instead (which is probably what you intended in the first place).

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dhczsxeg/)

```
$('.event').on("dragend", function (event) {
    var parentStage = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).addClass(parentStage);
});
```

---

However, you can also just add the class to the element when it is appended into the `td` element that the `drop` event is fired on. In doing so, you don't need another event listener for `dragend`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/ov5mtvrs/)

```
$('table td').on("dragenter dragover drop", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.type === 'drop') {
        var id = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text', this.id);
        var $draggable = $('#' + id).detach();
        $draggable.appendTo(this);
        $draggable.addClass(this.id);
    };
});
```